# query by ListField(ReferenceField) and parants id

Tags: python, mongoengine

I have this models:

```
class Group(BaseDocument):
    movies = ListField(ReferenceField('Movie'), required=False)
    season = IntField()

class Movie(MovieBase):
    season  = IntField() 
    episode = IntField()
```

I whant to get Movie thats season is 5 and Movie parent id (Group) is parent_id, how can i do this?